# UINavigationController and UITableView issues in modalView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)showDirectMessage:(id)sender
{
    DetailMessageViewController * dmvc = [[DetailMessageViewController alloc] init];
    dmvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:dmvc animated:YES];
}
```

What I am trying to do here is to present a view which has a NavigationBar on top and a UITableView as the view inside. However as of now it only shows the UITableView. I am confused on what I need to change. In my DetailMessageViewController IB I dragged in a UINavigationController and put in a UITableView inside as a view. However, I hooked up the UINavigationController to the UITableView view's.. I think this is wrong. I don't know how am I supposed to do this. Can someone guide me through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use presenting new NavigationController with your ViewController.

```
- (IBAction)showDirectMessage:(id)sender
{
    DetailMessageViewController * dmvc = [[DetailMessageViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *naviContoroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dmvc];
    naviContoroller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    [self presentModalViewController:naviContoroller animated:YES];

    [naviContoroller release];
    [dmvc release];
}
```

Comment: and U can use "dmvc.navicationItem" to set navigationBar property such as title, left/right bar button item and so on.

Comment: okay... so what is the purpose of the UINavigationController in the IB?

Comment: I guess U want use UINavigationBar with your ViewController.
It will help U that "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS"
and

You should read Anatomy of a Custom View Controller(below link) on "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS"
http://bit.ly/lNvE1y - apple developer login required.

Answer (score 0):

```
DetailMessageViewController *dmvc=[[[DetailMessageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailMessageViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];    
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dmvc]autorelease];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```